# Whats the best way/method to backup and AWS EFS to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-efs

Amazon suggests using a backup EFS and data pipeline for EFS backups but I am thinking of a simpler method to do the backup on a s3 bucket. What are your thoughts/suggestions, any scripts?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use whatever Amazon does. However, for smaller projects where cost effectiveness overweights reliability, custom approaches could be utilized.

Checkout the **s3 sync** AWS CLI command. I believe that is what you are looking for:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html